# dividing elements in list to normalize data in Python

Tags: python, csv, normalize

I am trying to write a script in Python which normalizes a dataset by dividing all value elements by the max value element.

This is the script that I have come up with so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("infile") as f:
    cols = [float(row.split("\t")[2]) for row in f.readlines()]
    maxVal = max(cols)
    #print maxVal

    data = []
    with open('infile') as f2:
        for line in f2:                  
            items = line.split() # parse the columns
            tClass, feats, values = items[:3] # parse the columns
            #print items      
            normalizedData = float(values)/float(maxVal)
            #print normalizedData

            with open('outfile', 'wb') as f3:
            output = "\t".join([tClass +"\t"+ feats, str(normalizedData)])
            f3.write(output + "\n")
```

in which the goal is to take an input file (3 columns tab-separated), such as :

```
lfr about-kind-of+n+n-the-info-n    3.743562
lfr about+n-a-j+n-a-dream-n 2.544614
lfr about+n-a-j+n-a-film-n  1.290925
lfr about+n-a-j+n-a-j-series-n  2.134124
```

1. Look for the maxVal in the third column: in this case is would be 3.743562
2. Divide all values in the 3rd column by maxVal
3. Output following desired results:

> ```
> lfr   about-kind-of+n+n-the-info-n    1
> lfr   about+n-a-j+n-a-dream-n 0.67973
> lfr   about+n-a-j+n-a-film-n  0.34483
> lfr   about+n-a-j+n-a-j-series-n  0.57007
> ```

However, what is currently being "outputted" is only a single value, which I am assuming is the first value in the input data divided by the max.
Any insight on what is going wrong in my code: why the output is only printing one line?
Any possible insight on solutions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code has incorrect indentation I suppose. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your intentions, following does the job. (Minor program flow corrections)

Also, instead of writing continuously to the file, I instead chose to store what to write & then dump everything to the output file.

**Update** - Turns out `list` creation takes same time as the excess `with` statement use, so, got rid of it completely. Now, writing continuously to the file, without closing it everytime.

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    cols = [float(row.split()[2]) for row in f.readlines()]
    maxVal = max(cols)
    #print maxVal

data = list()
f3 = open('out.txt', 'w')
with open('in.txt') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        items = line.split() # parse the columns
        tClass, feats, values = items[:3] # parse the columns
        #print items
        normalizedData = float(values)/float(maxVal)
        #print normalizedData

        f3.write("\t".join([tClass +"\t"+ feats, str(normalizedData), "\n"]))
f3.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the update: However, it is actually taking long according to timestamp. On same file, this is timestamp: `starting: 2013-12-01 12:22:30.164735`
`Finish: 2013-12-01 12:22:30.885216` which is actually longer than the original solutions at 0.7204 secs.

Comment: Wow, I think then your code in question is a bit different than what I interpreted. But the fractions of a second won't matter, go with the safer & more understandable code always (whichever you feel is good & does the job).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to open the output file *once* and keep writing to it as you process input lines. It'd also be much easier if you used the `csv` module to handle input and output:

```
import csv

with open("infile", 'rb') as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
    maxVal = max(float(row[2]) for row in reader)

with open('infile') as inf, open('outfile') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        tClass, feats, values = row[:3]

        normalizedData = float(values) / maxVal

        writer.writerow([tClass, feats, values])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("lfr") as f:
    cols = [float(row.split("\t")[2]) for row in f.readlines()]
    maxVal = max(cols)
    #print maxVal

    data = []
    output1 = ''
    with open('lfr') as f2:
        for line in f2:                  
            items = line.split() # parse the columns
            tClass, feats, values = items[:3] # parse the columns
            #print items      
            normalizedData = float(values)/float(maxVal)
            output1 += tClass + "\t" + feats + "\t" + str(normalizedData) + "\n"

            with open('outfile', 'wb') as f3:
                output = output1
                f3.write(output + "\n")
```

I have been working on it too, it seems like I was not creating an output variable by appending the results of each cycle. However, it seems that it is a bit slow (2 seconds to process a 4MB files). Can this possibly be optimized?

Comment: Yes, it can be optimized. Please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20311210/2689986) for that. Try to avoid writing to file continuously, instead store what to write & then dump all of it together.

Comment: I ran timestamps on your solution and my solution. In case you were curious: My solution (to process a 4MB file) takes 0.643 seconds to complete. Your solution (to process the same 4MB files) takes 0.663.

Comment: Updated mine. Check now. The `list` creation somehow compensated for the excessive `with` use in your code.